# Memory frequency and laptop overheating

Tags: laptop, memory, bios, ubuntu-16.04

I have an old Samsung rf411 notebook and upgraded its memory from 6gb (1x2gb and 1x4gb) to 8gb (2x4gb). The new memories model are Corsair Value Select - CMSO4GX3M1C1600C11.

When the memories arrived, I realized that they have a different frequency from its original pack. My notebook supports only 1333mhz memories, and the new ones runs at 1600mhz. I've read some comments that this it's not going to be a problem, but I now realizing that my laptop is overheating more than before.

I didn't find a way to change the memories frequency in the bios (see the following images please).

[Bios - SysInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGqHk.jpg), [Bios - Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOQDY.jpg)

The `dmidecode -t 17`:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0043, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0041
    Error Information Handle: 0x0045
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: 029E
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMSO4GX3M1C1600C11
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0046, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0041
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: 029E
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CMSO4GX3M1C1600C11
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

What should I do? Try to replace the memories to 1333mhz or configure the 1600mhz to run at a lower frequency? If so, how can I do this? I researched a lot and didn't find out a way to perform this at my bios or at the Ubuntu itself.

Comment: It's common for a laptop BIOS to be pretty restricted. You will probably not be able to change the frequency. You could try to use your 4GB 1333 stick as usually the slowest speed is used.

Comment: Are you trying to find out why your laptop is heating, or how to modify your bios to force your ram to run at a lower speed and voltage?

Comment: @Zymus, do you have any suggestion in how I can perform the downgrade in ram speed and voltage? My laptop is a Samsung rf411, and I don't have this option at my bios configuration. Do you know if it is possible to do it at the OS level? Running Ubuntu 16.04 here. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting the old ram sticks in to see if it still overheats?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1600MHz memory doesn't necessarily "run" on 1600MHz, it's just a spec for the maximum (manufacturer specified) memory clock the memory will run with.

All 1600MHz memories will run under 1600MHz. The maximum for your laptop's CPU is 1333MHz memory clock, so there is no changing that upwards.

The only reason the memory would make your laptop warmer, if indeed they run at the same 1333MHz speeds as the old memory, would be a larger current draw; Corsair says the voltages for your new memory are either 1,35V or 1,5V - so your laptop might be defaulting to 1,5V.

Comment: There is any specific way to verify if my laptop is defaulting to 1,5V?

Comment: Even if the memory is running at 1.5 V, the fact remains, your memory isn't the source of your laptop overheating problems.  If your laptop was that sensitive to a few degrees then it was already borderline overheating before you replaced the memory.

Comment: "The only reason the memory would make your laptop warmer ... would be a larger current draw;" Or, when you installed it, you (accidentally) rearranged some of the internal wiring and blocked the cooling air supply to something critical, like the CPU.

Comment: Internal wiring is unlikely be the culprit since in my experience (of couple of dozen memory/HDD/etc upgrades) 99% of laptops have no wires to "rearrange" near the serviceable areas like memory slots, HDD cages etc.
As for checking the actual voltage used - you can install a diagnostic software like RAMMon from PassMark or CPU-Z from cpuid.com.